# Return JSON in iOS application

Tags: php, ios, json

I'm trying to return a simple JSON in my iOS app through PHP file.

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$myarray = array("io" => 1, "tu" => 2);
$out = json_encode($myarray);

echo $out;

?>
```

iOS:

```
-(void)provePHP{

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite/myphpfile.php"]];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json"forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    NSError *error;

    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", jsonDict, error);

}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSLog(@"FINISH");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"Error");
}
```

I don't understand what I do wrong. I follow a lot of code I found on this site but no results in log.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753229/how-do-i-fetch-data-from-url-using-xcode-4-3-1-with-nsjsonserialization-class-r/9753963#9753963#answer-9753963) post/answer

Answer (score 0):

`connection:didReceiveData:` can be called multiple times in a connection. You should have an `NSMutableData` property that you keep appending data to in `connection:didReceiveData:`, then work with the data once it is all there in `connectionDidFinishLoading`.

I'd suggest adjusting your code to follow those guidelines and seeing if you still have the problem.

---

**EDIT**
If you are not getting the logs at all, you haven't properly set your class as the `NSURLConnectionDelegate`. See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) for information on what the delegate pattern is and how to make your class the delegate of a framework class in Objective-C.

Comment: I have some logs, but jsonDict is null. I've tried to use appendData but i got crash because data I received in delegate method is null...